# application.ini only with $this->getOptions()

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm noticing that `$config = $this->getOptions();` gets only the settings of the default `application.ini` file. If I have additional ini files, how can I tell `getOptions` about them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can merge new options read from some custom ini file into existing options in your Bootstrap.php as follows:

```
    $newOptions = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/newoptions.ini');        
    $this->setOptions($newOptions->toArray());
```

However, if you want to just read a custom file and have access to it through your application I would recommend storing it in a Zend_Registry:

```
$newOptions = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/newoptions.ini');
Zend_Registry::set('newoptions', $newOptions);
```

When they are in the registry you can always get them (e.g. in your actions) simply by calling get method:

```
$newOptions = Zend_Registry::get('newoptions');
```

Comment: +1. Additionaly - example how to merge config files and have them as Options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051390/taking-database-settings-out-of-the-application-ini-and-into-the-environment/5056712#5056712